# Casting ArcSDE table to IFeatureClassLoad

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, vb.net, editing

How do you cast an ArcSDE table to IFeatureClassLoad using ArcObjects?

I'm getting an error with this attempt below which is not the correct method:

```
   Dim pSDEFeatWksp As IFeatureWorkspace = workspaceFactory.Open(propertySet, 0)
   Dim table2 As ITable = pSDEFeatWksp.OpenTable("database.LOADER.tablename")

   Dim fclass As IFeatureClass = table2 ' <<< ERROR HERE
   Dim FCLoad As IFeatureClassLoad = fclass
   FCLoad.LoadOnlyMode = False
```

ERROR

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type
> 'System._ComObject to interface type
> 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass'...

I found [this example](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IFeatureClassLoad_Example.htm) which uses IFeatureClassLoad, however it is not dealing with a SDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the IFeatureClassLoad Manual:

> Remarks IFeatureClassLoad is an optional interface supported by
>   feature classes in ArcSDE and feature classes and tables in File
>   Geodatabase. It improves performance of data loading.
>
> With ArcSDE, putting a feature class in load-only mode disables
>   updating of the spatial index while data is loading. In a File
>   Geodatabase, putting a feature class or table in load-only mode
>   disables updating of spatial and attribute indexes while data is
>   loading. Taking the feature class or table out of load-only mode
>   rebuilds the indexes.
>
> While a feature class or table is in load-only mode, other
>   applications cannot work with the data. A feature class or table
>   should be placed in load-only mode only after acquiring an exclusive
>   schema lock on the feature class via the ISchemaLock interface.
>
> The dataset extent reported by the IGeoDataset::Extent property is
>   recalculated when a feature class is removed from LoadOnlyMode to
>   reflect the data present in the feature class.

As other noticed:

A) you're casting an ITable to IFeatureClass where that ITable is not a IFeatureClass (all feature classes can be casted as ITable, but not the other way around);

B) Only feature classes can be casted to IFeatureClassLoad in ArcSDE; That can only be done in File Geodatabases;

Comment: George, I find your last sentence confusing.  What can only be done in a FGDB?